# How to add a hyperlink to a password protected area of a website bypassing password login?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink to an area of another website requiring login to view files. The target website will be a photo gallery website which then will be accessible on my website.

My question is this. Is it possible to encode login information into a hyperlink therefore bypassing login when hyperlink is clicked? Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Client-side, this would be near-impossible, considering you cannot *send* form data via a hyperlink (though you can receive it, but then that gets dynamically added to the URL via method POST.) You can do this, however, by using Javascript by using a submit button (if the page doesn't have protection against `csrf`) which can dynamically inject parameters via a form, but then you would need a POST request *cross-domain* which is where my point with needing admin access comes in;

If you were to attempt to do this server-side, you would have to have admin access to *both* sites, certainly not just to site A. From then you can inject parameters into the hyperlinks via server-side scripting languages such as PHP or Python, which would then add the required information to the form upon landing on site B. But you  *must* (*must*) be careful, this opens up the potential of a serious security compromise depending on how you allow users to log in to your site. Assuming it's yours. Either way, this is still a bad idea, which concludes to my

**Shorter answer**: No.

Comment: If the site requires that the login is done via `POST` _method_ (what that page hopefully does - but there are many that allow both `POST` and `GET`), then you are right that it cannot be passed via url in the query part. That it would be impossible on client side is often not true, because you can send `POST` request cross domain using a form, either triggering with js or by user interaction over submit button (the button could be also styled as link if required) because many pages don't have protection against `csrf`. But this would not change anything on that this is a really bad idea.

Comment: Ahh, okay thanks. I didn't think of the fact that some pages don't have protection against csrf.

Comment: Sadly there are many companies that still don't have such a protection, neither in their login nor in the sensitive area the user only can reach if logged in. There are e.g. some big hosters where the admin area for their customers are still pretty prone to csrf.

Comment: Well I'm just sure that I do for my stuff, and I would suggest @ScottBaker to do the same.